# How do i get the numbers from the GetKey back to the List<float>? (Reverse of what i did)

Tags: c#

This is the code for the SetKey i loop over the Lists take out the numbers convert to string and put it in to the SetKey now i need to reverse the action using GetKey and put back the numbers to the Lists  so eahc List Point_X and Point_Y will have the numbers as before.

```
string[] xFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
                string[] yFrames = new string[wocl.Count];

                string X="";
                string Y="";
                for (int i = 0; i < wocl.Count; i++)
                {
                    X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
                    Y  = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);

                    for (int j = 0; j < wocl[i].Point_X.Count; j++)
                    {
                        xFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_X[j]);
                        yFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_Y[j]);


                    }

                    string tt = xFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
                    string yy =  yFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());



                     setting_file.SetKey(X, tt);
                     setting_file.SetKey(Y, yy);   

                }
```

Now tt is a string of number for example 122,33,44,55,121

Now i need to parse the numbers back. Now i need to take the string and parse the numbers and put them back to a float List:

List a = setting_file.GetKey(X);

But X is a key that present a string of numbers not a List of numbers.

This is the code in the OptionsFile of the functions GetKey and SetKey:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : GetKey
 * Description  : gets the value of the key.
 * Parameters   : key
 * Return       : value of the key if key exist, null if not exist
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public string GetKey(string key)
    {

      //  string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line;
        string line;
        int index;
        string key_value;
        key_value = null;

        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {


            index = line.IndexOf("=");


           //    value_of_each_key = line.Substring(index+1);



            if (index >= 1)
            {
                key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
                if (key_of_each_line == key)
                {
                    key_value = line.Substring(key.Length + 1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
            }


        }
        sr.Close();
        return key_value;
    }


/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : SetKey
 * Description  : sets a value to the specified key
 * Parameters   : key and a value
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public void SetKey(string key , string value)
    {
        bool key_was_found_inside_the_loop;
        string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line ;
        string line;
        int index;
        key_was_found_inside_the_loop = false;

        temp_settings_file = "\\temp_settings_file.txt";
        temp_settings_dir = path_exe + @"\temp_settings";
        if (!Directory.Exists(temp_settings_dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp_settings_dir);
        }

        sw = new StreamWriter(temp_settings_dir+temp_settings_file);
        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {

            index = line.IndexOf("=");
            key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
            value_of_each_key = line.Substring( index + 1);
         //   key_value = line.Substring(0,value.Length);
            if (key_of_each_line == key)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key + " = " + value);
                key_was_found_inside_the_loop = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key_of_each_line+"="+value_of_each_key);
            }

        }

        if (!key_was_found_inside_the_loop)
        {
           sw.WriteLine(key + "=" + value);
        }
        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();
        File.Delete(Options_File);
        File.Move(temp_settings_dir + temp_settings_file, Options_File);
        return;

    }
```

What i need is that in the List a it will contain the numbers from the string X

X is like a key the result in SetKey function is a Key = Value

For example : Hello = 122,33,44,55,66    Hello is like the variable X its the key and on the right hand the numbers are the key values.

So now i need to get the key X values and put them into the List

Cant figure out how to do it.

---

If before i had a List and i loop over it and took out the numbers from the List and created a string of the numbers and put them in the SetKey now i need to use the GetKey and take the numbers and put them back to the List

---

Edit:

```
public void Load(string path,string fileName)
        {
            string X = "";
            string t = path + "\\" + fileName;
            OptionsFile setting_file = new OptionsFile(t);
            for (int i = 0; i <= wocl.Count ; i++)
            {
            X  = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);

            }
            string test = setting_file.GetKey(X);
        }
```

Thep roblem is that if im running in the loop on the List wocl so when im running the program this List is count 0 or 1. But in the GetKey in the text file i might have 4 frames or 1 frame i mean how do i know on how much to count for in the loop ?

I tried with the wocl List for the test but now in the string test im getting the numbers of the first Frame_X_1 but thats it.

While in hte file it self it looks like:

```
Frame_X_1 =332,325,336,334,332,325,333,328,332
Frame_Y_1 =218,217,202,212,211,210,204,202,204
Frame_X_2 =270,325,336,347,321,325,333,328,332
Frame_Y_2 =257,217,202,282,156,210,204,202,204
Frame_X_3 =270,325,336,347,321,336,270,371,332
Frame_Y_3 =257,217,202,282,156,250,199,135,204
```

I mean when im running the program all the Lists are empty count to 0 and yet i need to retrive each key Frame_X_1 then Frame_Y_1 and so on...And i dont know how many keys there are.

Comment: So, basically you need to retrieve the numbers from a string like "123,32,544,..."?

Comment: Boomer right. I just edited my question please view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to a static helper class

```
public static List<T> ToListOf<T>(this IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            var list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                list.Add(item.ConvertTo<T>());
            }

            return list;
        }
```

then: `var myFloats = tt.Split(',').ToListOf<float>();`
elegant, no?  :)

EDIT

I forgot one more extension method:

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object source)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(T));
        }
```

Comment: PS - I see you are new here - please mark this as answer if that is the case.. or the other guy's if that is the case..

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what is different and moreover perhaps I am misunderstandinf your requirements, but I thought all you wanted was to convert a string of comma separated numbers into a list of floats.. isn't that right? In whcih case, I would think you jst need to do List<float> a = setting_file.GetKey(X).Split(',').ToListOf<float>();  Sorry, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a string like "123,33.44.55.66" and you know that this string is comma delimited. to retrieve the numbers:

```
string str = "123,33,44,55,66";
string[] strArray = str.Split(',');
```

you can then convert the `strArray` to any type compatible.

Comment: "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." whats that ? when will it be visible to eveyone ?

Comment: @user1526380 - you don't have edit privileges yet, so you can't edit somebody else's post.

Comment: @Marijn I was wondering that given the 1st person perspective it's written in... If it's the same person, they should use the account it was posted under, if it's not, the edit should be rejected... I'll skip either for now...

Comment: Yes noticed i cant edit yet. I will mark this question as solved.

Comment: @JonClements: user1526380 edited this answer rather than the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11535426/revisions)

Comment: @JonClements - i think all is clear now, I'll flag all these chatty comments for deletion.

Comment: @Matt - i think all is clear now, I'll flag all these chatty comments for deletion.